# Text doesn't wrap, breaks layout instead

Tags: html, css

I have a collection of divs as rows that can be variable width as they are inside a resizable container. The div contains text that I want to have a hanging indent. This works fine except in this example the first line is pushed underneath the red label when the width is too low.

When `.wrapper` is 450px everything is displayed properly. When it's 250px you can see how things break. I always want the `longtextthatwraps` span to be on the same line as the red label.

**[Here's a live example/fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7t9FP/)** and the source is as follows:

HMTL *(there is no whitespace between `.prefix` and `.part` but for readability...)*:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="padded excludes">
    <div class="parts first">
      <span class="prefix">Quisques:&nbsp;</span>
      <span class="segment level-0">
        <span class="part text">longtextthatwraps incorrectly (<a href="#" class="code">0000</a>-<a href="#" class="code">0000</a>)</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="parts">
      <span class="segment level-0">
        <span class="part text">consectetur adipiscing  (<a href="#" class="code">0000</a>-<a href="#" class="code">0000</a>)</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="parts"> 
      <span class="segment level-0">
        <span class="part text">quisque non mauris sed:</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="parts"> 
      <span class="segment level-1">
        <span class="part list-item">hendrerit (<a href="#" class="code">0000</a>-<a href="#" class="code">0000</a>)</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="parts"> 
      <span class="segment level-1">
        <span class="part list-item">non mauris sed (<a href="#" class="code">0000</a>-<a href="#" class="code">0000</a>)</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="parts"> 
      <span class="segment level-1">
        <span class="part list-item">lorem ipsum dolor (<a href="#" class="code">0000</a>-<a href="#" class="code">0000</a>)</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 250px;
    background: #c3dff5;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.padded {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.parts {
    padding-left: 80px;
}
.parts.first {
    padding-left: 0;
}
.prefix {
    color: #D12;
    font-weight: bold;
    min-width: 80px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.level-0,.level-1 {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 5px;
    text-indent: -5px;
    outline: 1px dotted #f0f;
}
.level-1 {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Help appreciated

Comment: Can you also put the `excludes` CSS rule in the question?

Comment: @taylorc93 the excludes rule just controls the color of the label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you remove the `first` class, move the `span.prefix` out of `div.parts` and add a `position: absolute` to it?

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7t9FP/5/)

### Update (css only)

For a css-only solution remove the `first` class, give a `position: absolute` to `span.prefix` and specify left position, for example `left: 25px`. This seems to work in IE7, too.

[Updated JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7t9FP/10/)

Comment: I'd like to avoid modifying the HTML and solving it with CSS only if possible

Comment: If you are ok with absolute positioning of span.prefix, check my updated answer

Answer (score 6):

Hmmm, I believe I have a CSS solution to your problem, though I'm sure there are other ways out there to get the behaviour you're looking for.

For `.prefix`, I gave the style:

```
.prefix {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

And then I added another definition:

```
.parts.first .level-0 {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

I hope this is what you're looking for! Here's the [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7t9FP/6/) to show you what it results in. If this isn't your objective, please let me know and I'll be happy to help you further!

Comment: This works and a vote for a CSS-only solution, I'd like for a solution that also works in IE7

Answer (score 1):

Use `position:absolute;` and `margin-left`.

```
.first > .prefix{
  position: absolute;
  left:10px;
}

.first > .level-0{
  margin-left:80px;
}
```

Lines 17-24 of [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SNVKW/)

Answer (score -1):

I created a simplified version that will float each section, one to right and section to left and gives them a percent unit. Try to add your indent levels.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
       <span class="red">Quisques: </span>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
      <span class="level">consectetur adipiscing  (<a href="#" class="code">0000</a>-<a href="#" class="code">0000</a>)</span>
      <span class="level">quisque non mauris sed:</span>
      <span class="level">consectetur adipiscing (0000-0000)</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

### CSS

```
 .wrapper {
  width: 250px;  
  background: #C3DFF5;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 12px;
}

.red {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;  
}

.left {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  width: 70%;
}

.level {
  display: block;
  outline: 1px dotted #FF00FF;
}
```

Live demo http://jsbin.com/apaqop/1/

Comment: I'm not looking for alternate HTML markup nor a half-baked answer where the original problem isn't solved

Answer (score -1):

Please see this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7t9FP/37/)

You have to add in CSS like

```
 .wrapper {
    width: auto;
    background: #c3dff5;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    min-width:250px;
    float:left;
  }
```